# Can't build chart with data from database

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

I can't build chart with data from database. Tried like this, but it don't work

**Controller:**

```
public ActionResult Chart()
{
    return PartialView("_Chart");
}
```

**In main view:**

```
img src="@Url.Action("Chart")"/>
```

**Partial view (*_Chart.cshtml*):**

```
@using TestProject.Models;

@{
    DateTime[] xVal = new DateTime();
    Decimal[] yVal = new Decimal();

    TestProjectContext db = new TestProjectContext();
    var deals = from d in db.DealsDirectory
                select d;

    deals.ToList().ForEach(x => xVal.Add(x.Date));
    deals.ToList().ForEach(y => yVal.Add(y.Price));

    var Chart = new Chart(width: 600, height: 400)
        .AddTitle("Зависимость цены от времени")
        .AddSeries(
            name: "USD",
            xValue: xVal,
            yValues: yVal,
            chartType:"Line")
        .Write();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code has some basic syntax problem which will prevent your code to even properly compile!

The below snippet is not valid !

```
DateTime[] xVal = new DateTime();
Decimal[] yVal = new Decimal();
```

You can not assign a `DateTime` object to an Array/Collection of `DateTime`s

You can use [implicit variable declaration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/implicitly-typed-local-variables) along with your LINQ query expression.

This should work

```
@{      
    var db = new TestProjectContext();    

    var xVal = db.DealsDirectory.Select(g => g.Date).ToArray();
    var yVal = db.DealsDirectory.Select(g => g.Price).ToArray();

    var Chart = new Chart(width: 600, height: 400)
        .AddTitle("Зависимость цены от времени")
        .AddSeries(
            name: "USD",
            xValue: xVal,
            yValues: yVal,
            chartType:"Line")
        .Write();
}
```